# Java - getting value from an array using string

Tags: java, arrays, string, int

I need to make an int array using Strings instead of ints. 
EX: `int["number2"] = 0; instead of int[2] = 0;`

Does anyone know how to do this?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Java doesn't support associative arrays, but you could use a [HashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html):

```
Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
map.put("key1", 25);
map.put("key2", 4589);
```

`map.get("key1")` will return 25.

Answer (score 5):

you could use a HashMap - see [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) for more info!

Comment: Or more generally, any kind of `Map`.

Answer (score 2):

You are not looking for an *array* but for an [*associative array*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_array).

In Java, in practice, every class that implements [`Map`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) can be used as an associative container, since they can map keys to values (`TreeMap<K,V>`, `HashMap<K,V>`, and so on)

Answer (score 1):

This syntax looks very like a [map in Groovy](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Collections), In Java, you could use something like a `Map<String, Integer>`.